# Cyrillic URLs encoding in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, encoding

I'm trying to extract links from website that uses cyrillic characters.

Link example:

```
<a href="/catalog/?filter=Ножницы"><span>Ножницы</span></a>
```

I use encodeURI function to encode URL and get this result

```
encodeURI("/catalog/?filter=Ножницы");

"/catalog/?filter=%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B"
```

When I visit this URL, web browser doesn't display any results.

But Google Chrome encode the same link as

```
catalog/?filter=%CD%EE%E6%ED%E8%F6%FB
```

And this link does work. How can I in JavaScript encode cyrillic links  the same way that Google Chrome does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this problem because function encodeURI() work with UTF-8 but you have Win-1251. Start from this question [How to convert utf-8 string to urlencoded win1251 in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914085/how-to-convert-utf-8-string-to-urlencoded-win1251-in-javascript)