# Is it possible to set accept-charset for new FormData (XHR2) object or workaround

Tags: javascript, ajax, character-encoding, form-data, xmlhttprequest-level2

Here is example code (http://jsfiddle.net/epsSZ/1/):

HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/echo/html" method="post" name="fileinfo" accept-charset="windows-1251">
  <label>Label:</label>
  <input type="text" name="label" size="12" maxlength="32" value="får løbende" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Send standart">
</form>
<button onclick="sendForm()">Send ajax!</button>
```

JS:

```
window.sendForm = function() {
  var oOutput = document.getElementById("output"),
     oData = new FormData(document.forms.namedItem("fileinfo"));
  var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  oReq.open("POST", "/echo/html", true);
  oReq.send(oData);
}
```

When i submit this old way via standart form submit, then request payload looks like this:

```
------WebKitFormBoundary2890GbzEKCmB08rz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="label"

f&#229;r l&#248;bende
```

But when i submit this AJAX way, then it looks little different:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryPO2mPRFKj3zsKVM5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="label"

får løbende
```

As you can see, in former case there is some chars is replaced with character entities,
but in case of using `FormData` there is plain string, which is of course good because it's utf-8, but is there any possibility to make it behave like standart form submit ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer to your question is **No**. You cannot change it. According to [XMLHttpRequest2 TR](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#interface-formdata), `FormData` constructed data is **explicitly** encoded to `UTF-8`. With no mention of allowing to change it.

The usual mimeType or Content-Type=charset become invalid for multi-part requests, since it is handled differently for the exact same reason.

To quote,

> If data is a FormData
>   Let the request entity body be the result of running the multipart/form-data encoding algorithm with data as form data set and with **UTF-8 as the explicit character encoding**.
>
> Let mime type be the concatenation of "multipart/form-data;", a U+0020 SPACE character, "boundary=", and the multipart/form-data boundary string generated by the multipart/form-data encoding algorithm.

Hope this helps!

**Update**

If you are willing to forgo

`new FormData(document.forms.namedItem("fileinfo"));`

for

`new FormData().append("name", "value")`

there might be a workable solution possible. Let me know if thats what you are looking for.

**Another Update**

Did a little bit of running around. [Updated fiddle with all modes](http://jsfiddle.net/aravindbaskaran/epsSZ/4/)

So this is the story,

1 `form with accept-charset="utf8"` => default behavior

The content does not require any additional escaping/encoding. So the request fires with the text intact as `får løbende`

2 `form with accept-charset="windows-1251"` => your case

The content requires additional escaping/encoding, since the default charset of the browser here is utf8. So the content is escaped, and then fired, i.e. the content sent is `f&#229;r l&#248;bende`

3 `FormData constructed with form element`

The content does not require any additional escaping/encoding, since it defaults to `utf8`. So the request fires with text as `får løbende`.

4 `FormData constructed, and then appended with escaped data`

The content is still in the utf8 encoding, but it doesn't hurt to call `escape(content)` before appending to the form data. This means the request fires with text as `f%E5r%20l%F8bende`. Still no dice right?

I was wrong, nope. Looking closer[read => staring for a few minutes....] at

`f&#229;r l&#248;bende` and

`f%E5r%20l%F8bende`

Then it all fell into place - `%E5` (Hexadecimal) = `&#229;` (Decimal). So basically `escape()`is Javascript's way of doing things, the `%` based encoding, which is not HTML friendly.

Similarly `&#;`, as we know is HTML's way of encoding. So I put another mode to ajax, [which is what you are looking for, I'm guessing]

5 `FormData constructed, and then appended with html-escaped data`

The content is still in utf8 encoding. Doesn't hurt to escape it like HTML encoding, using this wonderful piece of code from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18237140/1304559). And voila, the request fired with the text `f&#229;r l&#248;bende`

[Updated fiddle with all modes](http://jsfiddle.net/aravindbaskaran/epsSZ/4/)

Hope this helps clear it out!

**UPDATE for windows-1251 full support**

This `привет får løbende` input was failing in earlier mode 5. Update fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/epsSZ/6/.

Uses a combination of solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2711936/1304559 and mine. So the problem is escaping everything. So now escaping only characters not present in the windows-1251 charset.

This helps it I hope!

Comment: Would be nice to see solution with `append` if it is not too complex, but this answer is yet satisfactory.

Comment: Updated the answer with `append` solution. Have to say, thank you for the question!

Comment: @Dfr Does the solution with `append` help in any way?

Comment: not quite, beacuse it escapes also all windows-1251 characters, which is not desired. Currently i'm escaping it on server with `InLatin-1_Supplement` unicode set

Comment: Can you tell me an example?

Comment: Yes, this is example of `perl` regular expression:
`$data =~ s/\p{InLatin-1_Supplement}/"&#".ord($1).";"/eg`

Comment: Ok, is the last mode 5 in http://jsfiddle.net/aravindbaskaran/epsSZ/4/ not doing the same? Can you give me an example input that doesn't work in the expected way for mode 5?

Comment: Yes, here is it "привет får løbende"

Comment: Ah, yes. Think I got your problem, there is a way we can do it, just like the browser. :) Hold on

Comment: Updated the answer with windows-1251 full support

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for this question, I enjoyed myself! :)
Replace

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/echo/html" method="post" name="fileinfo" accept-charset="windows-1251">
```

by

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/echo/html" method="post" name="fileinfo" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

The problem is the accept-charset is `windows-1251` instead of `utf-8`

After

```
oReq.open("POST", "/echo/html", true);
```

you can also add

```
oReq.overrideMimeType('text/html; charset=UTF-8');
oReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

but this is not what fixes the problem.

Good luck. :)

Comment: Unfortunately this solution didn't worked for me. This sounds weird, but i need to post this form as windows-1251 and get those character entities from browser.

Comment: Maybe you can send UTF-8 and convert windows-1251 php side with [this](http://php.net/manual/fr/ref.iconv.php#48209) for example