# Angular 13 FormData append filename encoding

Tags: angular, file-upload, urlencode

Uploading a file in Angular with the following code

```
const formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file, 'NameToBeEncoded % ÄÖÜ.pdf');
this.http.request(new HttpRequest('POST', url, formData)).subscribe();
```

leads to a request with the following:

`Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="NameToBeEncoded % ÄÖÜ.pdf"`

instead of something like this:

`Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename*=UTF-8''NameToBeEncoded%20%25%20%C3%84%C3%96%C3%9C.pdf`

RFC2183 states for `filename`:

> Parameter values longer than 78 characters, or which contain non-ASCII characters, MUST be encoded as specified in RFC 2184.

and RFC6266

> "filename*" uses the encoding defined in [RFC5987], allowing the use
> of characters not present in the ISO-8859-1 character set

is there any way to use FormData.append and get the right Content-Disposition filename encoding?

Comment: Maybe this help you somehow https://stackoverflow.com/a/22529662/5888230